# How to use Magit to git log / git grep to find expressions across all previous commits

Tags: magit

I am using Magit and was wondering how to revert to a specific commit that contained a specific expression. First I need to find the expression across all commits content. How to do this? In command line it would be something like git grep / git log. Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In Magit:

- Open the Magit log buffer with <kbd>l</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> (lowercase `L` twice).
- Customize the log with <kbd>L</kbd> and search for
  commit messages with <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> or for changes with <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.
- Once you entered your search value, press <kbd>RET</kbd> and refresh the buffer with <kbd>g</kbd>. You will see only commits that match your search.

Or you can directly open the log buffer with your options with <kbd>l</kbd> → set your options → <kbd>l</kbd>.

[image]

In git documentation https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Sltstringgt you can find more information about how to use the `-G` option

> -G
>
> Look for differences whose patch text contains added/removed lines that match .
> To illustrate the difference between -S --pickaxe-regex and -G, consider a commit with the following diff in the same file:
>
> - return frotz(nitfol, two->ptr, 1, 0);
>   ...
>
> - hit = frotz(nitfol, mf2.ptr, 1, 0);
>
> While git log -G"frotz(nitfol" will show this commit, git log >-S"frotz(nitfol" --pickaxe-regex will not (because the number of >occurrences of that string did not change).
>
> Unless --text is supplied patches of binary files without a textconv >filter will be ignored.

Comment: This is fantastic, exactly to the point, what I needed! Just out of curiosity, is it possible to search for only commits where the regex is added, not deleted? Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know for sure but I didn't find the possibility to search only the added lines.

Comment: Thanks for checking, much appreciated.

Comment: Great answer.. to add to the discussion, if I understand correctly, using the `-p` flag gives you the specific patches (diffs) that involve the pattern searched for. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qse43.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qse43.png)

Comment: How to set `ignore case` e.g. show `Foo` if searching for `foo`?

Comment: How to search within the whole text not of the commit message, but of the files?

Comment: "and refresh the buffer with g". I don't have "g" option. Any ideas?